# Pact of Research in Civilization V

Tags: civilization-5

What are the requirements to have the option to sign a Pact of Research with another Civ?

Comment: Note that if you can't select Research Pact in the diplomacy screen, if you mouse-over it will tell you why it's unavailable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both sides need enough money for the agreement, and at least one side has researched Philosophy.

The cost for a research agreement scales with the era of the more advanced player and with the game speed:

```
Era         Quick  Standard  Epic  Marathon
-------------------------------------------
Classical   134    200       300   600
Medieval    167    250       375   750
Rennaisance 167    250       375   750
Industrial  201    300       450   900
Modern      234    350       525   1050
Future      234    350       525   1050
```

You can also have only one active research agreement per civilization, and research agreements are not possible during war (as bwarner pointed out).

If the enemy civilization has not enough money for the research agreement you can also gift (or loan it against gold per turn) the necessary gold to them.

Comment: You also can't be at war with each other, and you can only have a single research agreement active with each civ.

Comment: How much money I need?

Comment: I've signed a research agreement before for 200 gold.  Maybe the difficulty level plays into the cost as well as the era?

Comment: I've had it cost as little as 167 and as much as 400. The cost goes up based on the lowest tech you (or they) have.

Comment: I think gamespeed alters it as well.

Comment: @Raven That could very well be so, I only play standard speed.

Comment: @Raven You were right. I've added the costs depending on game speed.

Answer (score -3):

To enter a research agreement, both parties need to have the required amount of gold and both need to have researched Philosophy.

Comment: It is enough if one side has researched philosophy.

Comment: Does it matter which side?